# React-Native Module in Swift with async function throws is not a recognized Objective-C method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swift, objective-c, react-native

I am trying to export a swift module [according to react-native's documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#exporting-swift) but I run into the following error when I try to call this function in my `javascript` file. I believe the issue has to do with calling an `async` method in my swift code. So I'm not sure how to export and call an `async` method from my swift file when creating a native module in react-native.

[image: exception error object-c methor]

Here is the AppleMusicAuth.swift file that contains the `async` method I'm trying to export

```swift
//
//  AppleMusicAuth.swift
//
//
//

import Foundation
import MusicKit

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
@objc(AppleMusicAuth)
class AppleMusicAuth: NSObject {

  @objc
  func getAuthStatus() async -> Void {
    let response = await MusicAuthorization.request()
    print(response)
  }
}
```

Along with my AppleMusicAuth.m file that makes use of `RCT_EXTERN_METHOD` method for exporting the module to my JS application

```objectivec
//
//  AppleMusicAuth.m
//
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>


@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(AppleMusicAuth, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getAuthStatus)

@end
```

And the Javascript files that import and call the module and method for use

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { AppleMusicAuth } = NativeModules;
export default AppleMusicAuth;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-native';
import AppleMusicAuth from '../nativeModules/AppleMusicAuth';

type Props = {};

const App: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  return (
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            AppleMusicAuth.getAuthStatus();
          }}
          title="Button"
          color="#841584"
        />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Feel like this question needs more attention, there's currently no objective c support for MusicKit so swift is the only option but as far as I can see there's no way of using async await in RN modules I feel like PromisesSwift may be worth looking into but not sure.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**: my recommendation as of 10.01.2023 is to use expo-modules-core as it has support for this use-case.

See: https://docs.expo.dev/modules/get-started/

Example: https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/20645

#### Original Answer

I just ran into this, here is my workaround.
Instead of exporting an `async` function to React Native/Objective-C, we can export a regular function which then calls the `async` one.

- To call an async function from a normal function in Swift we can use [`Task`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-fix-the-error-async-call-in-a-function-that-does-not-support-concurrency)
- To send the result back to React Native we can use [events](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#sending-events-to-javascript).

```swift
  func myAsyncFunction(_ data: NSDictionary) async -> Void {
    // Processing...
    self.sendEvent(withName: "MyEvent", body: "The result")
  }

  @objc
  func myExportedFunction(_ data: NSDictionary) -> Void {
    Task {
      await myAsyncFunction(data)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would like to add that the reason `async` doesn't work with React Native is because the function gets added a completion handler in Objective-C.

We can import `#import <PRODUCT_NAME-Swift.h>` header in Objective-C to see what's available. If you open that header file you can find your `async` method has been added a completion handler which isn't supported by the bridge.

Comment: Lifesaver of an answer, thank you! I was also able to send results back to React Native with a callback of type RCTResponseSenderBlock as explained in the RN docs. It just has to be declared as @escaping in the exported (non-async) function.